# port number not accessible when running webpack-dev-server

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, webpack, port, wds

I have a centOS 7.2 box as my web server hosted in aws. I found something interesting : when I run my web site using a nginx docker container, I'm able to access it from my local machine. i.e. run docker command

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 my-nginx-image
```

and access the web site through the below url (my local machine is connected to that aws host machine via a vpn connection)

```
http://10.77.20.253/index.html
```

This works perfectly well. However, when I try to host the site using webpack-dev-server, i.e.

```
webpack-dev-server  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

I can access it from that web server with no problem, but I can't access it from my local machine. I always get a timeout error.

I then did a

```
netstat -anp
```

on that linux box, I noticed that when running from docker, it is listening on

```
     :::8000
```

while when I run from wds, it was listening on

```
     0.0.0.0:8000
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing here, so far I have tried

```
webpack-dev-server --host localhost --port 8000
webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1--port 8000
webpack-dev-server --host 10.77.20.253  --port 8000 (the internal ip address)
```

but none of them works.

Any thoughts on it??

Comment: Are you using EC2? If that's the case, did you open port 8000 to your IP in the instance Security Group?

Comment: definitely not a fire wall issue, nor a iptable issue. As I said, when I run through docker, I can access it from my local machine

Comment: yes, but on port 80

Comment: Check if you have another web server running on 80. `docker run -d -p 8000:80 my-nginx-image`
and access the web site through `http://10.77.20.253/index.html`. It is not possible. What happen if you stop the container?